# Mismatch between progam (C++ ABI 1002) and lib (C++ ABI 1009) build version:

Tags: c++, version, mismatch

```
Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.

The library used 3.0 (wchart_t, compiler with C++ ABI 1002, wx containers, compatible with 2.8)

and your program used 3.0 (wchart_t, compiler with C++ ABI 1009, wx containers, compatible with 2.8)
```

My Ubuntu is 14.04 with GCC version 6.2.0. How to solve this version mismatch issue?

Comment: Having an ABI version mismatch is pretty fatal.  The library was just compiled with a compiler that is too incompatible with yours.  Either too old or a completely different flavor, like Clang.  You'll have to rebuild the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is probably being built with different compiler version than the library was built. As a general rule, recompiling the library with the same compiler version should help.

Also some other tricks might work, as using `-fabi-compat-version` switch, or some hints might be found here: https://github.com/eranif/codelite/issues/825 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wx-users/bzXESX__828.